# Using javascript to ask if the user is sure they want to delete the data

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to run a function that calls some Javascript to ask the question  "Are you sure you want to delete this customer?" But my link to the java-script does not seem to work. All I get at the Java-script end is the word remove. It is supposed to ask if they are sure and if not return them back to the page they clicked on. If they are sure, then delete the data.

This script checks to make sure there is no other data connected to the customer's data. If there is they are not allowed to delete it. But if there is nothing attached they can delete it but I want to make sure that's what they want to do.

I think my problem is in my links but not sure.

```
function checkcustomeruse($custid,$pid,$name){{}
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from signings WHERE pid = ? AND custid = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $custid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
$number = $number_of_rows;
 if($number == 0)
 {

    echo '<a href="javascript: deleteAlert(custid =' . $custid . ',' . 'name =' . $name . ');">Remove</a>';
 }
 else
 {
  $Message = 'You can not delete this customer because it has signings attached to it.';
       header("Location: viewallcustomer.php?Message=" . urlencode($Message));  
 }

}
```

This is the javascript

```
function deleteAlert(custid,name){
    var conBox = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + name);
    if(conBox){
        location.href="formpross.php?processtp=deletecustomers&delete=yes&custid";
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

`function deleteAlert(custid,name){
       var conBox = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + name);
       if(conBox){
          location.href="formpross.php"; 
       }
       return conBox;
    }`

Comment: Doing that will not do me any good now It is not even getting to this script my problem is in the link to this script

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing out your Javascript function a little differently. The escaped single quotes turn into single quotes around the values we're sending into the javascript function.

```
 echo '<a href="javascript: deleteAlert( \'' . $custid . '\',\'' . $name . '\');">Remove</a>';
```

Also, we need to return false if the Javascript function results in cancelling the action.

```
function deleteAlert(custid,name){
    var conBox = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + name);
    if(conBox){
        location.href="formpross.php?processtp=deletecustomers&delete=yes&custid";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this echo '<a href="javascript: deleteAlert( custid =\'' . $custid . '\',\'' . 'name =' . $name . '\');">Remove</a>'; But still does not work all I get is Remove

Comment: The problem is your syntax when calling your Javascript function. You don't need it to output as deleteAlert(custid=6,name=Jerry). That will not work because that's [not Javascript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). You need it to output simply as deleteAlert('6','Jerry') or even deleteAlert(6,'Jerry'). Numbers do not require single quotes.

Comment: would this be more like it  echo '<a href="javascript: deleteAlert(' . $custid . ','  .  $name . ');">Remove</a>';

Comment: Closer. It would be exactly like the code I already posted in the answer above. The slashes are necessary - they allow us to put single quotes into the resulting Javascript. Just try it out: echo '<a href="javascript: deleteAlert( \'' . $custid . '\',\'' . $name . '\');">Remove</a>';

Comment: That gets me to the JavaScript but it puts the word remove into the upper left side of the screen with nothing else. Not what I expected. I was hoping for a box to popup on the screen that where on asking are you sure you what to delete this. JavaScript is not a language I know very well. Could you point me to some info on how to do the box popping up

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me when I tested it. Can you edit your original question and post just a bit more of the code around your Javascript function? I'm curious how that function is getting printed into HTML.